# How to create a Popup view with up and down moving animation in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I need  a popup view with a down swipe to close the popup

The pop up should be animated according to the movement of the finger

Comment: Seems that you have one solution for your problem, please mark your reply as answer, it may be helpful to others.

Comment: The first answer to this question is mine. You can check it out...

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this animation by adding **[PanGestureRecognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/pan)** in your Layouts(frame,grid,stacklayout etc.)

I have provided an example of this type of animation right here

Xaml for popup:

```xaml
<pages:PopupPage
        x:Class="Examaple.Views.Controls.Popups.DemoPopup"
        xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        BackgroundClicked="Cancel_Tapped"
        CloseWhenBackgroundIsClicked="False">
    <Frame
            x:Name="RecordPlayFrame"       
            BackgroundColor="White"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <PanGestureRecognizer  PanUpdated="PanGestureRecognizer_PanUpdated" />
            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
    
    </Frame>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

C# code for the `PanGestureRecognizer_PanUpdated` popup animation:

```cs
private async void PanGestureRecognizer_PanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
{           
    switch (e.StatusType)
    {
        case GestureStatus.Running:
            if (e.TotalY > 0)
            {
               await RecordPlayFrame.TranslateTo(0, e.TotalY);
               Verticaltransition = e.TotalY;                     
            }
            break;
        case GestureStatus.Completed:
            if (Verticaltransition > 75)
            {
                await RecordPlayFrame.TranslateTo(0, 200,100);
                if (PopupNavigation.Instance.PopupStack.Any())
                {
                    await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();
                }
            }
            else
            {
               await RecordPlayFrame.TranslateTo(0, e.TotalY);
            }
            break;
    }            
}
```

I hope this answer will eliminate your problems

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this too.  https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup. Might need to change some implementation to make it animated though. This will allow you to have any custom popup that you want.